# Resize Group type node in react-flow-renderer using mouse

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-flow

I want to add **subflow** (group type node) on button click and resize it later with mouse and add nodes inside this group with drag and drop. I have searched a lot but all I found is you have set `parentNode` of child to do this.

I want all this with mouse drag and drop. Is it possible with free version of `React-flow-renderer` ?

**Edit**

SandBox- > https://codesandbox.io/embed/headless-architecture-6xbzu9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Below I have attached `onDragEnd` function.. It works but when I drop a node inside group, node position changes and it goes outside group. upon moving group it moves with the group which means its parent is set correctly but position is not correct. tried to set manual position but still it is not working.

```
const handleDragEnd = useCallback(
(event: React.MouseEvent<Element>, node: Node) => {
  let groupNode: Node | undefined = undefined;
  if (node.type === ConstantsFlowChartNodeTypes.GROUP) return;
  nodes.map((nds: Node) => {
    if (nds.type === ConstantsFlowChartNodeTypes.GROUP) {
      console.log(
        nds.type,
        nds,
        nds.type === ConstantsFlowChartNodeTypes.GROUP
      );
      if (
        nds.position.x <= node.position.x &&
        nds.position.x + parseInt(nds.style?.width?.toString() || "0") >=
          node.position.x &&
        nds.position.y <= node.position.y &&
        nds.position.y + parseInt(nds.style?.height?.toString() || "0") >=
          node.position.y
      ) {
        groupNode = nds;
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(groupNode);
  if (groupNode) {
    const position = {
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY,
    };
    setNodes((prevNodes) => {
      return prevNodes.map((nds) => {
        nds.parentNode =
          nds.id === node.id ? groupNode?.id : nds.parentNode;
        // nds.positionAbsolute = position;
        console.log(event);
        return { ...nds };
      });
    });
  }
},
[]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resize Group**

As of v11.3, Resizing node is possible and `reactflow(previously react-flow-renderer)` library has a component for that.

So after pondering upon the issue so many times, I realized, I was actually getting position of `mousePointer` instead of actual node. I had 2 scenarios to deal with.

- What will be position if user is dragging node from outside of group to inside Group(subFlow).
- What will be the position if user is dragging node from inside of group to outside Group(subFlow).

**Outside to inside Group**

```
nodeWithUpdatedPosition.position = {
            x: draggedNode.positionAbsolute?.x! - targetGroupNode.position.x,
            y: draggedNode.positionAbsolute?.y! - targetGroupNode.position.y,
          };
```

You have to subtract position of `targetGroupNode` because if you add parent to any node, its position will be relative to that group(targetGroupNode) meaning if you give `draggedNode` position of `{x:0, y:0}` then it will be placed at top-left corner inside `targetGroupNode`. Subtracting from `positionAbsolute` will make the position relative to `groupNode`.

**Inside to Outside Group**

```
nodeWithUpdatedPosition.position = draggedNode.positionAbsolute!
```

This resolved all of the issues related to positioning of nodes. It works even if user drag, zoom in or zoom out the canvas.

[Working codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-https-db94q1)

Comment: other answers to this question and official documentation is dropping node at position of mouse pointer. which will confuse user and flowchart design will be disturbed.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible!

If I understand your question you need to be able to drag/drop your nodes between groups.
You can use "onDragEnd" prop in react-flow. Just pass a function to it and than whenever you drag/drop something in the canvas, it gives you the exact drop position and with some calculation, you can find the target group and update the "parentNode" of dragged node

```
 function handleDragEnd (event, node) {
  // node contains the absolute the drop position
 }

<ReactFlow
 ...your props
 onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
/>
```

Comment: yes but the question is how can I get the target group and I also want to resize group with mouse...

Comment: You need to map over all of your groups and do some calculations with their absolute positionProperty and their width and height to find the target group.
And for the resize feature you need to get the pro version to access to the resize example https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/nodes/resize-rotate

Comment: Kindly check , I have update my question.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve your problem of position changing when dropping Node, send reactflow instance as an argument to function. Then you can use it as shown in drag n drop example as shown below:

```
 const position = reactFlowInstance.project({
    x: event.clientX - reactFlowBounds.left,
    y: event.clientY - reactFlowBounds.top,
  });
```

This is helpful in setting the position relative to reactflow instance.
or

use layout libraries like dagre or elkjs for a better tree structure. you can check the example on the below link for that
[Layout algorithm](https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow/issues/5)

Coming to point 2: The Node should stay in subflow
I will suggest you use a custom node and make the node structure as follow:

```
{
id: '4b1',
data: { label: 'Node B.A.1' },
position: { x: 20, y: 40 },
className: 'light',
parentNode: '4b',
extent: 'parent' // this property is important to make the node stay inside parent
```

}

If you need further assistance feel free to share code sandbox link and I can show you there as well.

Comment: still not getting satisfied results... 
    `event.client X, Y -- 501 293
    reactBound Left, Top -- 286 155
    event.ClientX - reactBoundLeft -- 215
    reactInstance.Project() -- {x: -1045, y: -519}
    Group -- {x: 7, y: 24}
    Dragged Node -- {x: 7, y: 24}`

Comment: problem gets worse when is drag canvas to right which makes the coordinates negative..

Comment: this is the sandbox example.. the section i have commented out worked well when canvas is not dragged right..... https://codesandbox.io/embed/headless-architecture-6xbzu9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: if you uncomment my code under `const position = reactFlowInstance.project....` you will see its working only for default canvas position.